# Describe the topological dual of a norm space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let
\begin{equation*}
    X=\left\{x=(x_{n})\in\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}\phantom{a}|\phantom{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^{n}|x_{n}|}<\infty\right\}.
\end{equation*}
be. Prove that the function
\begin{align*}
    ||\cdot||_{X}&\colon X\to\mathbb{R}\\
    &\phantom{a}x\longmapsto\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^{n}|x_{n}|}
\end{align*}
is a norm in X. Also, describe the space $X^{*}$ and the norm $||\cdot||_{X^{*}}.$

Attempt: It is clear that $ || \cdot ||_{X} $ is a norm in X.

Let $$\phi\colon l^{\infty}\to X^{*}$$ be given by $$\phi_{y}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x_{n}y_{n}},\phantom{a}\forall y\in l^{\infty}.$$

Note that for every $y\in l^{\infty},$ we have
\begin{align*}
    |\phi_{y}(x)|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x_{n}y_{n}}\right|&\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|x_{n}y_{n}|}\\
    &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|x_{n}||y_{n}|}\\
    &\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^{n}|x_{n}||y_{n}|}\\
    &\leq ||x||_{X}||y||_{\infty}.
\end{align*}

The above argument, since $ x \in X, $ shows that $ \phi $ is well defined and linear. Therefore, we have $$||\phi_{y}||\leq ||y||_{\infty},\phantom{a}\forall y\in l^{\infty}.$$ Thus, $ \phi $ is continuous.

I have a doubt. Is the $ \phi$ function injective? I ask why I will use it later.

Let $x^{*}\in X^{*}$ be. Define the sequence $$y=(y_{n})=x^{*}(e_{n}),\phantom{a}\forall e_{n}\in X.$$

Notice that if $ m \in \mathbb {N},$ then
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{n=1}^{m}|x^{*}(e_{n})|=\sum_{n=1}^{m}{a_{n}x^{*}(e_{n})},
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
    a_{n}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{|x^{*}(e_{n})|}{x^{*}(e_{n})} & x^{*}(e_{n})\neq 0\\ 
0 & \text{opposite case} 
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=1}^{m}{|x^{*}(e_{n})|}&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}{a_{n}x^{*}(e_{n})}\\
    &=x^{*}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}{a_{n}e_{n}}\right)\\
    &\leq ||x^{*}||\left|\left|\sum_{n=1}^{m}{a_{n}e_{n}}\right|\right|_{X}\\
    &\leq ||x^{*}||
\end{align*}
Doing $ m \rightarrow \infty, $ we have 
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|x^{*}(e_{n})|}\leq ||x^{*}||.
\end{equation*}

The above argument guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{*}(e_{n})}$ is convergent. So, $y=(y_{n})=x^{*}(e_{n})\in l^{\infty}.$ Note that $||y||_{\infty}\leq ||x^{*}||.$ Let $x\in X$ be. Then
\begin{equation*}
    T_{y}(x)=x^{*}(x)=x^{*}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x_{n}e_{n}}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x_{n}x^{*}(e_{n})}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x_{n}y_{n}}
\end{equation*}
and $\phi$ is surjective.

Let $y\in l^{\infty}.$ Then $x^{*}=\phi(y).$ Since $ \phi $ is surjective, then $ y '\in l ^{\infty} $ exists, with $||y'||_{\infty}\leq ||x^{*}||,$ such that $\phi(y')=x^{*}.$ Since $ \phi $ is injective, we have $y=y'$ and $||y||_{\infty}\leq ||\phi_{y}||.$

Thus, $||\phi_{y}||=||y||_{\infty}$ and $\phi$ is an isometric isomorphism.

The argument is correct?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Show that $X^\ast$ are isomorphic to $l_\infty$ (with sup-norm), and $\varphi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2^nx_ny_n$ where $y\in l_\infty$, $\|\varphi\|=\|y\|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the (many) Riesz representation theorems says that

> Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space. Then for $1<p<\infty$ the dual of $L^p(\mu)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L^q(\mu)$, where $q$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$. The same holds for $p=1$, provided that $\mu$ is a sigma-finite measure.

You fall in that case: Define a measure on $\mathbb{N}$ as $\mu(\{n\})=2^n$ and extend it to $P(\mathbb{N})$ by $\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E}2^n$. Your space $X$ is just $L^1(\mu)$. It is immediate that $\mu$ is sigma-finite, so the dual is $L^\infty(\mu)$. Note that this does not differ from $\ell^\infty$ as a set and that the norms are equal, so the dual of $X$ is simply $\ell^\infty$ with the usual $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm.

PS: In case you do not know abstract measure theory, I suppose you are familiar with the result $(\ell^1)^*=\ell^\infty$ and its proof. You can always mimic this proof with $X$ replacing $\ell^1$; if you find trouble with the details, add them to your post!

Comment: I wrote a prove, more or less, about what he said in P.S. It is right?

Comment: @Darkmaster I believe you are right. About injectivity, if $\phi_y=\phi_{y'}$, then $\phi_y(e_n)=\phi_{y'}(e_n)$ for all $n$, but this means that $y_n=y'_n$ for all $n$, hence $y=y'$.

Comment: @JustDroppedln I get it. Thanks for answering.